# Can I use python's pyglet library on android?

Tags: python, android, pyglet

The title is my question. I know you can run python on android, but would it be possible to make a gui app with pyglet? I'm thinking android might not have the required libraries? If it is possible, how much work would be required to get it going and what would I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

No. From [pyglet documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): `pyglet works on Windows, OS X and Linux`

Comment: I did see something about android running on a linux kernel...